# Image of a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a question about the image of a homeomorphism ...

If $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open and $f: U \rightarrow f(U)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a homeomorphism, then necessarily $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ? 
Everything comes from the perturbation of the identity by a contraction, for in this case $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I would appreciate to give me light on this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Invariance of domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) theorem gives you a quick answer in the positive, but there might be a more elementary approach.